# Difference between "import X" and "from X import *"?

Tags: python, import, difference

In Python, I'm not really clear on the difference between the following two lines of code:

```
import X
```

or

```
from X import *
```

Don't they both just import everything from the module X? What's the difference?

Comment: How do you know that there's a difference?

Comment: I believe it is largely a namespace issue ... `import X` allows you to maintain separate namespaces ... while `from X import *` places them in the local namespace

Comment: If you don't know what `from X import *` imports don't use it. If you know what it imports ... don't use it. You're just polluting your namespace.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

After `import x`, you can refer to things in `x` like `x.something`.  After `from x import *`, you can refer to things in `x` directly just as `something`.  Because the second form imports the names directly into the local namespace, it creates the potential for conflicts if you import things from many modules.  Therefore, the `from x import *` is discouraged.

You can also do `from x import something`, which imports just the `something` into the local namespace, not everything in `x`.  This is better because if you list the names you import, you know exactly what you are importing and it's easier to avoid name conflicts.

Comment: What's better: `import x` later `x.my_function(arguments)`, OR `from x import my_function` later `my_function(arguments)`?

Comment: I prefer the former, but both are widely used and acceptable.

Answer (score 16):

`import X`: this imports everything as `X.var1`,`X.var2`,etc

`from X import *` : this imports everthing as `var1`,`var2` etc ,i.e it floods the local namespace

see the difference after two calls:

```
>>> import math
>>> len(globals())  
5                          #no of variables in namespace
>>> globals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, 'math': <module 'math' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so'>, '__package__': None}
>>> 
>>>
>>> from math import *
>>> len(globals())
47                     #no of variables in namespace
>>> globals()
{'pow': <built-in function pow>, 'fsum': <built-in function fsum>, 'cosh': <built-in function cosh>, 'ldexp': <built-in function ldexp>, 'hypot': <built-in function hypot>, 'acosh': <built-in function acosh>, 'tan': <built-in function tan>, 'asin': <built-in function asin>, 'isnan': <built-in function isnan>, 'log': <built-in function log>, 'fabs': <built-in function fabs>, 'floor': <built-in function floor>, 'atanh': <built-in function atanh>, 'sqrt': <built-in function sqrt>, '__package__': None, 'frexp': <built-in function frexp>, 'factorial': <built-in function factorial>, 'degrees': <built-in function degrees>, 'pi': 3.141592653589793, 'log10': <built-in function log10>, '__doc__': None, 'math': <module 'math' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so'>, 'asinh': <built-in function asinh>, 'fmod': <built-in function fmod>, 'atan': <built-in function atan>, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, 'copysign': <built-in function copysign>, 'cos': <built-in function cos>, 'ceil': <built-in function ceil>, 'atan2': <built-in function atan2>, 'isinf': <built-in function isinf>, 'sinh': <built-in function sinh>, '__name__': '__main__', 'trunc': <built-in function trunc>, 'expm1': <built-in function expm1>, 'e': 2.718281828459045, 'tanh': <built-in function tanh>, 'radians': <built-in function radians>, 'sin': <built-in function sin>, 'lgamma': <built-in function lgamma>, 'erf': <built-in function erf>, 'erfc': <built-in function erfc>, 'modf': <built-in function modf>, 'exp': <built-in function exp>, 'acos': <built-in function acos>, 'log1p': <built-in function log1p>, 'gamma': <built-in function gamma>}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
import X
```

Creates a label in the local namespace that references the module object.

```
from X import *
```

Creates a label for every member attribute of the `X` module, directly in the local namespace.

Both operations add `X` to `sys.modules`, true, but the effect on the local namespace is the difference.

Answer (score 3):

There are differences, some simple, others requiring more explanation.

`import X` just imports the entire module (read: "runs the module"), and assigns it a name in the local scope. The name can be aliased like so: `import X as Y`

`from X import *` imports all of the *attributes* of module `X` into the local scope, by default. Here's an example of different usage:

```
# Assume that module `X` contains an `opendb` function
import X
X.opendb('Y')

# VS.
from X import *
opendb('Y')
```

Where this gets *slightly* more complicated is when a module defines `__all__`. This changes the semantics of `from X import *` to mean "import everything *that is listed in the* `__all__` *property*." This allows module writers to have control over which functions and objects are exported from their module.

Answer (score 3):

You should *never* use `from X import *` unless you really know what you're doing. You can get symbols from module X that conflict with symbols from another module or even your own program. The only exception I have to that rule is sometimes `from math import *`.

You can use the form `from X import y` to get a single thing from a module.

If you use the `import X` form, not only do you make your usage of the module explicit `X.y` but you can now use the `reload` function if you make changes to the module and need to reimport it.

Answer (score 1):

`from X import *` imports all elements from the module `X` into the current namespace.
`import X` imports X but doesn't "merge" the namespaces. E.g.:

Module X:

```
def foo(): pass
BAR = 12
```

Your code:

```
from X import *
foo() # calls X.foo
print BAR # prints 12
```

Or:

```
import X
X.foo()
print X.BAR
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's use this as an example of our module definition

```
def my_func():
    return 1
```

the from import will pull everything into the current namespace

```
from X import *
print my_func()
```

the normal import will create a module object called X in the current namespace

```
import X
print x.my_func()
```

in addition with from X import my_func can be used to only import that functionality.