# How to use sqlAlchemy table shema to load data

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, schema

I have two scripts `schema.py` and `load_data.py`. In `schema.py`, I define the schema for over 20 tables using sqlAlchemy Base. Two of the tables look like:

**schema.py**

```
Base = declarative_base()
meta = MetaData()

class Table1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table1'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

class Table2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table2'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bdate = Column(Date)
...
class Table20(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table20'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bdate = Column(Date)
```

I want to use my `load_data.py` to copy those ~20 tables from one database to another. My question is how to create the table in `load_data.py` using the schema I defined in `schema.py`?? Following the examples in [Introductory Tutorial of Python’s SQLAlchemy](http://pythoncentral.io/introductory-tutorial-python-sqlalchemy/), I use `import` to load all the table schema class, but I find it too messy. Is there any better way to handle this situation??? I am new to sqlAlchemy,please bear me if this question seems too naive.

**load_data.py**

```
from schema import Base, Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4, Table5, Table6, Table7, Table8, Table9, Table10,..., Table20

src_engine = create_engine('sqlite:// sqlite_test.db')
dst_engine = create_engine('postgresql:///postgresql_test.db')

Base.metadata.create_all(dst_engine)

tables = Base.metadata.tables

for tbl in tables:
    data = src_engine.execute(tables[tbl].select()).fetchall()
    for a in data: print(a)
    if data:
        dst_engine.execute( tables[tbl].insert(), data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `from schema import *`, which imports all members from a module. See also [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270954/difference-between-import-x-and-from-x-import) regarding the difference between `import schema` and `from schema import x`.