# Python import and from x import. What is real difference between them?

Tags: python

I had read two other question about it.
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270954/difference-between-import-x-and-from-x-import)

But i dount understand this behavior:

```
#mod1 __init__.py
g = 5

#mod2 __init__.py
from mod1 import g
def bar():
    print g

#main1.py
import mod1
mod1.g = 10
from mod2 import bar
bar() # prints 10

#main2.py
from mod1 import g
g = 10
from mod2 import bar
bar()
```

So question is why main1 prints 10 and main2 prints 5? What is the real difference between from import and import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this has to do with scope

mod2 imports mod1 (g=5)

main1 sets mod1.g to ten, and asks mod2 to print the value of mod1.g

main2 sets main2.g to ten, but mod1.g is unchanged

Comment: thanks. so main1 uses reference to mod1.g and main2 uses copy of mod1.g right?

Comment: By doing `from mod1 import g`, `g=10` in deed refers to the variable defined in mod1

Comment: main2 doesn't use a copy.  It just creates a new variable, g

Answer (score 0):

The point is that in `main1()` you set the variable `g` in the module `mod1` to 10, so calling `bar()` returns 10. I think thats clear.
In `main2()` you first set `g` to 10, but when `mod2` imports `mod1`, it gets a fresh scope with an initial set of variables. Try to print `g` in `main2()` **after** calling `mod2`, I guess it will print the changed value (10).

You must keep in mind, that `import` just tells the interpreter to look up whatever is called in the corresponding module (as if you would open your script again). Of course the value assigned to a variable does not change in your script when the variable is changed by your program. The interpreter reads the .py file only once (and in your case once again), that is when importing it.

Comment: i tried it prints 5. from mod1 import g from mod2 import bar g = 10