# Using a dictionary to execute a method of an object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to execute the following code

```
def get_data(full_file_path, **kwargs):

    file_extension = full_file_path.split(".")[-1]

    method = {"data":read_table(full_file_path, **kwargs),
              "csv":read_csv(full_file_path, **kwargs)}
    data = pd.method.get(file_extension)

    return data
```

I am getting the error:

```
File "C:\Users\code\src\data\make_dataset.py", line 7, in get_data
    method = {"data":read_table(full_file_path, **kwargs),
NameError: name 'read_table' is not defined
```

Does someone know if it is possible to choose a method of an object, based on a dictionary?

Thanks in advance.

ps.: yes, I have ìmported `pandas as pd`.

Comment: If you have imported `pandas as pd` then you have to refer to the functions as `pd.read_table`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "import X" and "from X import \*"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270954/difference-between-import-x-and-from-x-import)

Comment: you probably want to prepend a `pd.` before using `pandas` functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References to functions in Python are just like normal names. The problem in your code is that you're actually trying to call the functions in your dictionary definition. I've split the lookup into a couple of steps in this version of your function to make it clear:

```
def get_data(full_file_path, **kwargs):

    file_extension = full_file_path.split(".")[-1]

    method = {"data": pd.read_table,
              "csv": pd.read_csv}
    read = method[file_extension]

    data = read(full_file_path, **kwargs)

    return data
```