# Is from os import path importing a class called 'path' or importing a function called 'path'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been confused about this for a while now, I still have no idea what `from x import y` really means. All I know is that it imports y from the file x(?)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270954/difference-between-import-x-and-from-x-import) might help. Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710551/use-import-module-or-from-module-import). Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439480/from-import-vs-import?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have file name `x.py` and that file there has a multiple function module like

```
def a():
    print('You\'re A!')
def b():
    print('You\'re B!')
def c():
    print('You\'re C!')
def d():
    print('You\'re D!')
.........
```

From the above `x.py` file when you need a specific module `a` then you can define that module name by `from x import a`. When you need to import all module from the `x.py` you can define then `from x import *`.